# Why Java Swing main usage runable for execution

Tags: java, swing

I am learning Java Swing. So times I see codes like following in the main:-

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    // create an example of the data structure
    HashMap<String, String[]> attributes
            = new HashMap<String, String[]> ();
    attributes.put("fruits", new String[]{"apples", "peaches"});
    attributes.put("drugs", new String[]{"euthanasipame", "aspirine", "analgine"});

    // create a ComboFest
    ComboFest fest = new ComboFest(attributes);
    fest.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 260));

    // create a window and display the ComboFest in it
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(fest);
    frame.pack();
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() { frame.setVisible(true); }
    });
}
```

why does it need to run inside a thread by the Runnable? What is the pros and cons? Coz many times I saw people don't use it at all. Please let me know?

Comment: In general all the code that creates the Swing components should be in the Runnable, not just the setVisible(...). Swing is single threaded. Not using the Runnable can cause random problems and debugging random problems is difficult if not impossible. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples on how to structure your code to make sure you create components and update the GUI on the EDT.